# Should it be if() or if ()?

Tags: formatting, coding-style, preferences

When you have line of code with a parenthetical statement, do you include a space before the parenthetical?

For example, should it be

`if()`

or

`if ()`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I prefer without, but it doesn't really matter, does it?

Comment: What language? Some editors auto-trim a space there?

Comment: This is totally subjective, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is better place for it.

Comment: I can't believe this question got 8 answers in less than a minute. I'm guilty for answering too.

Comment: @Rei Miyasaka, Yes! I too! But i have my answer!!!

Comment: @Rei Miyasaka If a question can be answered in 30 seconds or less, it will always get a lot of answers.

Comment: Stylecop demands the space which happily coincides with my world view of whitespace ~= readability, so my ifs remain spacey.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subjective, but I prefer having the space because it looks cleaner, or maybe because that's just how I learnt to 'do it' with language constructs such as `switch`, `if`, `while` and `for`.

You could do it without the space if you like it to 'look like' a function call, because I don't use a space for function calls.

Comment: +1.  I prefer the space.. it's not a function call.

Comment: Yep. I use the space because it's not a function call so I explicitly *don't* want it to look like one. Better yet, no brackets at all, in languages that allow it (eg Python).

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely a personal preference (or a team preference when working with other developers) and really doesn't matter in the long run, but I (and everybody else I know) prefer no space.

Whatever you choose, just be consistent. Nothing bothers me more than looking at code that has multiple coding styles all mixed together with no consistency.

Comment: I would have to agree with that!! No space for me, I find that easier to read personally.

Comment: +1 for consistency - I can't stand messy code

Answer (score 2):

I prefer keeping it to the default behavior of the IDE that I use, in order to reduce the risk of the source control system flagging insignificant differences between my edits and those of my co-workers. The same goes for other styling issues such as how many spaces to indent, whether to indent using space or tab and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the only developer on the project, pick whatever you prefer, otherwise stick with whatever convention the team is using.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a matter of taste. I personally use the version with the space `if ()` in order to distinguish this visually from a function call where I don’t use a space (as in mathematics).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio automatically changes it to `if ()`, so I follow that.

I think it's marginally more readable, but the brackets provide some space already as it is so I think this is one of those totally-doesn't-matter things.

Comment: I don't know what version of Visual Studio you have, what language you're working in, or what code formatting extensions you have...but mine has never done this (and I would spend a day trying to figure out how to disable it if it did).

Comment: C# in VS2010. It's been doing it since VS2008 or possibly even VS2005.

Comment: My version of Visual Studio does this, but it could be ReSharper I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

In php it doesn't matter, but you probably knew that. I'm putting a space in between. I think it's more readable, probably because for functions I put no space in between and 'if' is not a function :)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not to use a space, for me it makes it easier to read later and many of the people I know prefer no space as well for reading purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a space because not all languages use bracket delimited if statements. Leaving a space is the safer habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

Interpreters and compilers ignore it, So you can ignore it too!!!

Comment: -1 Consistency in style counts because maintaining code is hard and it doesn't matter how much compilers ignore your keyboard mashing, the compiler doesn't maintain your code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if the compiler/language ignores white-spaces.  (all though off the top of my head i can't think of any that would balk at the "if" statement with a space).  Outside of the language specifics, it's your preference.  That being said, I prefer no space as it makes the code look more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Do whichever, but learn to read either without getting caught up about it.

Same deal as with bracket style.

There, that's about as meaningful an answer I can give to this.